# testing out opencv's resizing functions but i keep getting this error

Tags: python, opencv

been tinkering with python's open cv library and wanted to try resizing an image.

```
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread("photos/volcano.JPEG")

if img is None:
    sys.exit("Could not read the image.")

def rescaled_img(img, scale=.5):
    width = int(img.shape[2] * scale)
    height = int(img.shape[2] * scale)
    dimensions = (width, height)

    return cv.resize(dimensions, img, interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)

imgresized = rescaled_img(img)

cv.imshow("volcano", img)
cv.imshow("resized", imgresized)

k = cv.waitKey(0)

if k == ord("s"):
    cv.imwrite("volcano.JPEG", img)
```

after running this code on the atom text editor's console i get:

```
return cv.resize(dimensions, img, interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'resize'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'dsize'. Expected sequence length 2, got 1271
>  - Can't parse 'dsize'. Expected sequence length 2, got 1271
```

Any idea what as to what I am doing wrong?
I am still new to coding and using stackoverflow so I apologize if I sound ignorant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer for your problem.
you have to convert your width and height to integer numbers to use them.
see my resize function code:

```
def rescaleimage(frame,scale,interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA):
   width = int(frame.shape[1] * scale)
   height = int(frame.shape[0] * scale)
   dimensions = (width,height)
   return cv.resize(frame,dimensions,interpolation)
```

Comment: good catch on OP taking the wrong elements from `.shape`. however, OP already uses `int()`, so that was not the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution and even OP already uses it. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should [vote it up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Answer (score 1):

I think you got the parameter order wrong in `cv.resize`

```py
return cv.resize(dimensions, img, interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)
```

This is the function I use:

```py
def resize(src, factor, interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA):
    """ Resizes an image by the specified factor keeping the aspect ratio

    :param src: Image to be resized
    :param scale: Resize factor
    :param interpolation:
    :return: Resized image
    """
    height = src.shape[0]
    width = src.shape[1]
    dimensions = (int(height*factor), int(width*factor))
    return cv.resize(src, dimensions, interpolation)
```

Also, you can use **imutils library** (https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils), that already implements a couple of useful functions for OpenCV.